# TFS "Visual Studio Test" task not executing tests on Test Agent

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We are using TFS 2015 and I am trying to get a "Visual Studio Test" task to work in our build definition. I cannot seem to get our Automated UI Tests to run on our designated TestAgent (UITestRunner).
When we build the release project I have selected binaries from our $(Build.BinariesDirectory) copied to UITestRunner. UITestRunner has Test Agent 2013 update v5 installed on it and is linked without error to a BuildServer which has the controller equivalent.
When we execute the tests it appears to try and run the UI Tests in the $(Build.BinariesDirectory) rather than being directed to the files on the Test Agent. I have even set the Test Assembly path under "Execution Options" to be a UNC path for UITestRunner.

Has anyone encountered this before and willing to advise?

Here is the build definition for Visual Studio Test:

[image: Visual Studio Test Task - Build Definition]

I have tried to specify the TestAssembly path using UNC and alternative methods but it fails to run tests on the machine "UITESTRUNNER".

I have commented out the "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" and "Run Functional Tests" tasks. Using these I do actually see the UI tests run but for some reason it only runs the first test and non others.

Comment: Could you please share the build definition settings especially for the "`Visual Studio Test`" task, also share the test logs for troubleshoo. Capture screenshot should be better.

Comment: Can you run the UI tests with Visual Studio locally? And please share the test logs here for troubleshooting.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT  - The UI test do run locally on my machine without error but when I run them using the "Visual Studio Test" task they fail to run. I would attach the log but it simply outputs that its attempting to run pre-requisite checks I have as part of my first test.  I have added debug information to identify where it is trying to run the tests and I get:

Machine Name: DICK
Current Dir: C:\Builds\MaxwellSmart\_work\9\TestResults

To me this indicates it is not running on UITestRunner.

I hope this gives you what you need and thank you for your help

Comment: Ah, you'd better copy and paste all the test log messages here for analysing. BTW, have you set the build agent to run as interactive mode? To run UI test you need to set the build agent run as interactive mode if you are using `Visual Studio Test` task.. See [Interactive vs. service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#account). Also, can you run the UI test with `Run Functional Test` task (Enable `Interactive Process` in `Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment` step) ?